# sending message using MFMessageComposeViewController failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, imessage

I am facing one issue for send message to multiple contacts :

301 up contacts : Message app is not opening, If we click invite on multiple time then iMessage is opening but it will take more time (2 minute) to load message

351 up contacts : Message is open with black new message screen then come back to our application with out opening message screen.

Here is my code:
contacts is the array of phone number

```
NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray array];

for (User *user in users) {
    if (user.phone.length) {
        NSString *strphonenumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.phone];
        [contacts addObject:strphonenumber];
    }
} 

MFMessageComposeViewController  *messanger = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc]init];
    messanger.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    messanger.recipients = contacts;
    messanger.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“body”;

    [self presentViewController:messanger animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I am getting this error:

```
<CKSMSComposeRemoteViewController: 0x12802f810> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.mobilesms.compose
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
NSString *strContacts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",add multipal contacts];

MFMessageComposeViewController *message = [[MFMessageComposeViewController new];
message.recipients  = @[strContacts];
```

Comment: I am already passing array of strings in recipients. I am facing this for more than 50 contacts only, less than 50 contacts it’s working well.

Answer (score 0):

I to had the same problem then figured

`messanger.recipients` = // should always be an array of strings.

*Make sure the phone numbers you send to `messanger.recipients` are `NSString`.*

Comment: I am already passing array of strings in recipients. I am facing this for more than 50 contacts only, less than 50 contacts it’s working well.

Comment: @ZaidPathan : Could you post the code how you are creating array of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

set delegate to interface:

```
@interface ViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>{}
```

check if device is able to send message

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] ){
  //device is possible to send messages
}else{
  //device can't send messages
}
```

prepare message:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController* comp = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

 //set properties
 comp.body = @"body";
 comp.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:phone1, phone2, nil];
 comp.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```

open dialog:

```
[self presentViewController:comp animated:YES completion:nil];
```

determine result

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{
    //test result
    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            [self makeAlert:@"Result canceled"];
            break;
        //message was sent
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            [self makeAlert:@"Result sent"];
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            [self makeAlert:@"Result Failed"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //dismiss view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this method:

```
- (IBAction)sendSMS:(id)sender {

   MFMessageComposeViewController *controller =  
   [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){
        controller.body = @"Hello";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678",@"87654321", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Callback method:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{
     switch (result) {
       case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
             break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
             NSLog(@"Error occured");
             break;
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
             break;
        default:
             break;
     }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```